# How do I return a Promise and get the data from it?

Tags: angular, typescript, express, promise

I'm having trouble making a function that returns the data "array" that I want to consume using a Promise.
The tech  stack that I'm using is Angular, Typescript and Express.js. I can get the data to return inside of the getData() function however, the data is not passed on in the return statement, I just get an empty array in ngOnInit();

getData Function:

```
public async getData(user: any): Promise<any> {

        this._url = 'http://localhost:5000/account/data';

        const data = this._http.post<any>(this._url, user).toPromise();

        return data

 
    }
```

ngOnInit:

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    this._account.getData(this.login)
    .then((data: any) => {
      console.log(data)
    });

  }

result = [ ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (just to add **await** to yout http call):

```
public async getData(user: any): Promise {

    this._url = 'http://localhost:5000/account/data';

    const data = await this._http.post<any>(this._url, user).toPromise();

    return data
}

ngOnInit(): void {
   this._account.getData(this.login)
   .then((data: any) => {
      console.log(data)
   });
}
```

**EXTRA**: A better way to work with angular http Module, is the **OBSERVABLE** way:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


public getData(user: any): Observable<any> {
    this._url = 'http://localhost:5000/account/data';
    return this._http.post<any>(this._url, user);
}

ngOnInit(): void {
   this._account.getData(this.login)
   .subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log(data)
   });
}
```